`/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: Text file busy` Error after system update
I'm working on Next.js Project from past 4 - 5 months and it was working fine till yesterday. But suddenly today I'm facing some issue.
When I run yarn dev which runs command npx nodemon index.ts it gives the following error:
yarn run v1.22.22
$ next dev
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: Text file busy
error Command failed with exit code 126.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I did system update yesterday, maybe it's due to some kernel issues or the new node version have some bug?
I'm on Arch Linux with node version v22.2.0 and kernel version 6.9.2-arch1-1. Thanks for reading it to here, any help will be appreciated.

This seems to be related to the latest kernel version, temporary workaround is to set UV_USE_IO_URING=0 in your environment variables
so either
UV_USE_IO_URING=0 yarn dev

or
export UV_USE_IO_URING=0
yarn dev

reference: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/48444

thnx! worked with ubuntu 24.04 and kernel 6.9.2-060902-generic.
